# Ajax success not working

Tags: ajax

I have this:

```
public ActionResult GetBear(int bearId)
    {
        return Json(bear);
    }
```

Here is the ajax call to it:

```
$.ajax({ url: "correctUrl", dataType: 'json', data: { bearId: 2}, contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", success: function (data) {
                alert("something")
            }
```

GetBear gets executed, but the success method is not entered. What is the porblem?

I added error field and it says Internal server error. Why? I'm not comunicating with a server.

Comment: What error are you getting in error console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, check if you get alert or not ?

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "correctUrl",
dataType: 'json',
data: {bearId: 2},
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function (data) {
                alert("something")
            },
 error: function(data) {
 //AJAX request not completed
    alert("it shows error");
 }
```

And check if page(correctUrl) exist on which you send ajax request..

Answer (score 0):

First check URl Since you wrote function executing 
change your function return type from ActionResult to JsonResult